# Reference request: Moberly's translation of Mozart operas

Tags: mozart, opera

In the book "Three Mozart Operas" by R. B. Moberly, 1967, the author uses his own singable translations of Figaro, Don Giovanni, and The Magic Flute when quoting the liberetti.

**Did Moberly ever publish the entirety of these translations somewhere?** I find his translations excellent, beyond other singable translations that I so far have found (they are exactly as he says in the preface: "rhyme and fit the music and are singable, but have also been kept as accurate as possible.")

I can't find them, so I guess he didn't. After all it's possible that he only translated fragments of the liberetti for the purpose of writing this book. But I'm taking a chance by asking it here; please let me know if you have any information.